# how to add actAs when using symfony doctrine:build-schema

Tags: symfony-1.4, mysql-workbench, doctrine-1.2

Background:

(1) I use mysql workbench to design my database.

(2) Then I use "Synchronize Model" tool in mysql workbench to apply my modification to mysql database.

(3) Finally I use `symfony doctrine:build-schema` command to generate schema.yml according to database(For some legacy reason, I have to use Symfony 1.4).

Here comes the problem: I wanna add `actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }` to schema.yml, but `symfony doctrine:build-schema` command cannot do that.

The solution I can imagine is to write a shell to edit schema.yml. Clearly this is not an elegant solution.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1) What errors is given out by command `symfony doctrine:build-schema`

2) Try such code in schema.yml

```
Something:
  actAs:
    Timestampable:
  columns:
...
```

Comment: Having spent the whole weekend on Wow, sorry for replying late. Maybe I didn't describe clearly. Command symfony doctrine:build-schema gives no error. I just want command symfony doctrine:build-schema to add 'actas: Timestampable' to schemal.yml automatically

Answer (score 0):

I use [**MySQL Workbench Schema Exporter**](http://bit.ly/schemaexporter) (an open source PHP library project) to save time and complete all database model definition tasks in modeling process. Review this [**Installation Tutorial**](http://bit.ly/bitcoder-doctrine-exporter).

With MySQL Workbench Schema Exporter you can use Table Comments to define table behavior. To add a timestampable behavior to table definition put this in your comments:

```
{MwbExporter:actAs}actAs: [Timestampable]{/MwbExporter:actAs}
```

Then export your model (**.mwb file*) to YAML (**.yml file*) using [**MySQL Workbench Schema Exporter**](http://bit.ly/schemaexporter) and place it in ./config/schema/ folder in order to create an sql script and then load it to a database already configured with symfony. It's easy! just like this:

1. Export model to YAML

   `php bin/mysql-workbench-schema-export your_model.mwb`
2. Copy schema.yml resulting file to ./config/schema folder location
3. Create an sql script

   `php symfony doctrine:build-sql`
4. Now build your model physically with:

   `php symfony doctrine:build-model`